# Enigmatic Letters

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, letter-sequence

I call them **Recurro**, **Terminato** or **Perfecto** if the letters conform to my conditions.

**Recurro**:`A, B, G, H, K, N, Y, Z`

**Terminato**:`E, M, Q, W`

**Perfecto**:`C, D, F, I, J, L, O, P, R, S, T, U, V, X`

Find the conditions.

Clue: Corresponding lowercase letters are not necessarily in the same category.

Comment: If you combine all the letters it forms the incantation to summon Cthulhu.

Comment: I thought I had a partial solution for Recurro, but G doesn't seem to fit it. I was thinking that every letter has two equal segments and one different segment, but G doesn't follow that convention. Oh well.

Comment: Actually David I think you're onto something. The equal segments would be the lines going up and left from the bottom of the curve.

Comment: Almost wanted to say Perfecto letters are symmetrical, but there are too many symmetrical letters that don’t fit and too many asymmetrical  letters that do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have a logic

> The number of strokes required to write Recurro type letters is 3 and inverse of 3 is recurring

For others,

> Terminato type letters, 4 strokes are needed and inverse of 4 is terminating (need to check for Q, if it can be written differently)

And

> For Perfecto type letters either 1 or 2 strokes are enough and inverse of 1 or 2 is obvious.

Based on

> Tom's inputs, here is a complete solution:
>  Get the index of an alphabet, starting with A=1, proceeding futher like B=2,....till Z=26

and

> Get the number of 'different' strokes / line segments needed to write a letter in capital. 
>  Now divide the index by the number of strokes to get like
>   For 'A' : index = 1, strokes = 3 and thereby giving a fraction 1/3, which is recurring...(similarly others can be tested B with 2/3, G with 7/3 etc. - giving 'Recurro' type letters
>  For E, they are 5 and 4(5/4), M - 13 and 4 (13/4)..which terminate and thereby Terminato and
>  For C they are 3 and 1 (3/1), D - 4 and 2 (4/2) ... which end us with proper integers like 3,2, and so on and hence are 'Perfecto'.

Comment: How do you define “strokes”? I can write a B with just one stroke.

Comment: Wow, I actually thought about counting strokes, but I didn't consider taking the inverse. In addition, F and I (potentially R as well) take three strokes. Other than that, I like this answer

Comment: And what is the difference between perfecto and terminato if you accept two-stroke characters? 1/4 = .25 and 1/2 = .5. Those are both terminating. Q doesn't really work either.

Comment: I thought about counting them but you can write M or W with one stroke. While you could write E with two strokes.

Comment: You can [Rot13](http://www.rot13.com/) qvivqr gur N1-M26 yrggre inyhr ol gur ahzore bs fgebxrf gb tvir n erpheevat be grezvangvat qrpvzny be jubyr (cresrpgb) ahzore.

Comment: @Tom to get what ?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay, like A = 1/3 = 0.33..  &  B = 2/3 = 0.66..  (recurring) , C = 3/1 = 3 & D = 4/2 = 2 (perfecto/whole), E = 5/4 = 1.25 (terminating). You could call your strokes - smooth differentiable segments.

Comment: I write E with three strokes.

Comment: @Tom, good point you made, thanks ! Perhaps that is the solution. I have missed it. However, how it (I mean ROT13) is different in case of small-case alphabets? It is not. Is it not so ?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay No problem, just following-up your solution, and you could add this A1-Z26 numerator and 'number of strokes' denominator to your answer. A lower case letter like b would have two strokes. (I only used Rot13 to hide my first comment.)